# VS2012 Editor + Resharper 9 - Holding Ctrl key gets current block highlighted

Tags: visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting, resharper-9.0

In Visual Studio 2012, holding Ctrl key down without pressing other keys gets the current block highlighted after a bit less than one second:

[image: block highlight]

I have VS2012 with Resharper 9 (and Viasfora syntax highlight extension). I checked **all** fonts and colors and did not find any setting with this background. Tried to look also in Resharper options but this seems to come from some VS setting, maybe linked to the Dark theme...? Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it comes from the extension.